# How to list "labels" and "in use by" along with instances in a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am currently using the following piece of code to get instance list from a project (which seems to work ok):

```
gcloud compute instances list
    --format="csv(name,description,machineType,status,zone)"
```

However, looking at the response body for instances.list, I found labels but couldnt find where "In Use By" values are listed. I've tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
gcloud compute instances list \
    --format="csv(name,description,machineType,status,zone,items.labels.list())"
```

If it helps, I am looking for the values in red to be listed along with my instances.list output:
[https://imgur.com/FFeDHoW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcZnB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below commands to get the details using `gcloud compute instances list --topic` format:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format='csv(name,description,machineType,status,zone,labels,inUseBy,instanceTemplate.list())'
```

or

```
gcloud compute instances list --format='table(name,description,machineType,status,zone,labels,inUseBy,instanceTemplate.list())'
```

Sample Output:
[image]